# Number format exception in inflating xml for fragment

Tags: android, exception, android-fragments, android-xml

Good morning,
 I have a following fragment:

```
public class NewIntervPhotoFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.newintervphoto, container, false);
}
//rest of code goes here
```

Layout of xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/newintervPhotoDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/newintervPhotoDescription"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:lines="10"
    android:gravity="left|top"/>

 <Button 
   android:id="@+id/newintervPhotoItem"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   android:text="@string/TakePhoto"
   android:textStyle="@style/TextStyle"
   android:layout_below="@id/newintervPhotoDescription"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in styles.xml:

```
<style 
name="TextStyle">
  <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item> 
  <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

The style above is used in other xml files of the same project without problems.
In this form, I get fatal exception (part of logcat):

```
01-01 11:49:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 11:49:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(780): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   activity ComponentInfo{cz.triinfo.terminal/cz.triinfo.terminal.ui.NewIntervPhotoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-01 11:49:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(780): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-01 11:49:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(780): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-01 11:49:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(780): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '@2131165192' as integer
```

Now, when I replace `android:textStyle="@style/TextStyle"` by `android:textSize=20sp  android:textColor=FFFFFF` exception disappears. 
My question is: what did I do wrong in the first case i.e xml with `android:textStyle` and more generally, is possible use styles in Fragments?

Thanks in advance! 
styles.xml is placed in res/values and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style 
    name="TextStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item> 
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

So problem is **really** elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use android:textAppearance to apply styles instead of android:textStyle.

Comment: please upvote this one, as this is the correct answer! Thanks! I had the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

Check how your styles.XML matches up with the format on the android dev wesite : [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html). You've probably missed the `resources` tag.

**[EDIT]**: Just read your first comment and thought it's worth mentioning here (in case you did not check out the link I mentioned earlier):

```
<resources>
    Required
This must be the root node. No attributes.
```

Adding this would make you styles.xml look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="TextStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item> 
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

How 'bout giving it a try and THEN saying it's not a real solution?

Comment: Thank for your answer. I am using mentioned style in other xml files of the same project without problems. The problem is elsewhere.